# Texlive won't upgrade to latest version

Tags: texlive

I installed texlive-full on my elementaryOS system (which is based on Ubuntu 18.04).
Everytime I try to install a package using tlmgr, I get the following error.

```
tlmgr install moderncv
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr: Remote repository is newer than local (2017 < 2020)
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
Please see https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

So I went and grabbed the update-tlmgr-latest.sh.
When I run that script, I get another error message:

```
./update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

What am I missing?
`kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT` outputs `/`

Comment: Basically you cannot install LaTeX packages via `tlmgr` via the texlive that comes from a Linux dist. YOu should install the latex package from the Linux dist instead. If you so not know which Ubuntu package provides moderncv.cls, then install `apt-file` and run `sudo apt-file update` and then `apt-file search moderncv.cls`. This will tell you which Ubuntu package provides moderncv.cls and then you just install that Ubuntu package. Yes, this is very confusing, but that is how Debian altered the Upstream TeXLive and `tlmgr`

Comment: If you have installed `texlive-full` then you should already have all the LaTeX packages elementary OS/Ubuntu can offer you. The TeX live installed through the Debian repositories doesn't really use `tlmgr` and generally its `tlmgr` can't really be used for updating and installing packages. With the TeX live from the Ubuntu repositories you need to install packages via `apt`/`apt-get`. `moderncv` is included in [`texlive-latex-extra`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/bionic/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist), which you should already have if you have `texlive-full`